# How can I run gtk.main() asynchronsly in pygtk?

Tags: python, multithreading, pygtk

The basic code that I have so far is below. How do I thread gtk.main() so that the code after Display is initialized runs asynchronously?

```
import pygtk
pygtk.require("2.0")
import gtk

class Display():

    def __init__(self):
        self.fail = "This will fail to display"
        window = gtk.Window(gtk.WINDOW_TOPLEVEL)
        window.connect("destroy", lambda w: gtk.main_quit())
        window.show()
        self.main()            

    def main(self):
        gtk.main()

class Test():

    def __init__(self, display):
        print display.fail

d = Display()
t = Test(d)
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? What is the real problem you're solving?

Comment: I am trying to control a gtk window and its various elements from another class.

Comment: Your program should have only one main loop. Perhaps it should not be controlled by the Display class.

Comment: To put it differently, you should initialize all your "elements", then start the main loop. Your Test class should be part of the main loop and influence the display there, in event callbacks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put the `gtk.main` call after everything else.
If you need to have the controller in a separate thread, make sure you do all gtk related function/methods by doing gobject.idle_add(*widget.method*).

```
import pygtk
pygtk.require("2.0")
import gtk

class Display(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.fail = "This will fail to display"
        window = gtk.Window(gtk.WINDOW_TOPLEVEL)
        window.connect("destroy", lambda w: gtk.main_quit())
        window.show()            


class Test(object):

    def __init__(self, display):
        print display.fail

d = Display()
t = Test(d)

gtk.main()
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use Twisted with the gtk2reactor.

http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/howto/choosing-reactor.html

Comment: I like the idea, however it is kind of silly to have to import part of or a whole unrelated library to solve this issues. I managed to  solve this issue using gobjecct.idle_add() last year.